# different timezone for different date in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

NodeJS application running on a server in EST timezone.

When I try to parse two different date strings into objects on NodeJS on this server, its showing me **two different timezones** as below:

`new Date('09/30/2017');`

**Sat Sep 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (**EDT**)**

`new Date('01/31/2017');`

**Tue Jan 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (**EST**)**

Note: We are using NodeJS 0.8.19, but I also observed the same behavior with NodeJS 6.9.1.
Also, I am not seeing the behavior on my local.

Comment: no , it's showing daylight savings time vs standard time due to time of year that daylight savings is in effect

Comment: Thanks, that helps. We are using node-xlsx module to convert data to .xlsx file, when we pass these dates to the module and download the file in different timezone (IST), the date  '9/30' will be changed to '9/29' while the other one remains same. How to tackle this?

Comment: Try using UTC date